# Filter in ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am trying to apply a filter on a parameter in my `ui-sref` reference.

```
<a ui-sref="item.show({ itemId: item.id, itemName: item.name | slugify })">
```

However, the above is not working. How to I apply the `slugify` filter to `item.name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a function:

```
<a ui-sref="item.show({ itemId: item.id, itemName: getSlugifiedName(item) })">
```

And in your controller, something like that:

```
$scope.getSlugifiedName = function (item) {
    return $filter('slugify')(item.name);
}
```

Comment: Hi, isn't there another way? Currently, my links are not in any controller. I would have to create that function in the `$rootScope`. I have the same issue: I want to use *slugify* in url titles.

Answer (score 9):

Use parentheses for filter:

```
<a ui-sref="item.show({ itemId: item.id, itemName: (item.name | slugify) })">
```

Comment: Best Answer!!! No Controller coding, especially when you already made a filter and just want to also implement it in the `ui-sref` attribute.