# Using filters inside ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-filters

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494358/filter-in-ui-sref) answer, but it doesn't solve my problem, I want to generate the whole state name with my filter, not just use filter for my state parameters.

How can I have `ui-sref` to be generated from a filter like this?

```
  <a ui-sref="menuItem.key | srefFilter">                   
      <p>
         {{::menuItem.name}}
      </p>
  </a>
```

`srefFilter` is a filter that returns the state name based on value passed to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter in ui-sref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494358/filter-in-ui-sref)

Comment: @Shota I don't think you are right, using filters in state parameters is ok, I want to generate the whole state with a filter not its parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{{ }}` ([Angular expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_expressions.asp))

[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ETWQ0UTWudtJ75OUaKh4?p=preview)

```
<a ui-sref="{{someValue | srefFilter}}">This link has ui-sref with a filter</a>
```